# Laravel relations and pivots for two models

Tags: laravel

There are some papers from `Paper` model and some editors and reviewers from `User` model that are distinguished by a role field. The editors determine which reviewers must review which papers that are stored in `ReviewerPaper(user_id, paper_id)` model and the comments of reviewers are stored in `ReviewerComment(reviewer_id, paper_id, comment)` model. Hence we have `Paper, User, ReviewerPaper, ReviewerComment`. Because a reviewer may have multiple comments on a paper, I didn't include the comment field in `ReviewerPaper`. I need to delete comments of a reviewer once it has been free from reviewing a paper (equivalently `{paper_id},{reviewer_id}` is removed) and I want to do it by Laravel relations not by looping through the model data.

My solution was to include a field `via` in `ReviewerComment` which is a foreign key to `ReviewerPaper` but it seems to be messy.

I would like to know is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance

## Update

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes, JqGrid;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'family', 'gender', 'birth_date', 'phone', 'country_id', 'university', 
        'role_id', 'email', 'password', 'email_verified_at'
    ];
}

class Paper extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes, JqGrid;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'file', 'user_id', 'status'
    ];
}

class ReviewerComment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes, JqGrid;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'paper_id', 'comment', 'reviewer_paper_id'
    ];
}

class ReviewerPaper extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, JqGrid;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'paper_id'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Please provide your model relationship code and show your existing solution, messy though it may be.

Comment: @miken32 I provided the models

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it (or seen it done) like this, but in your shoes, I'd try it:

```
$table->foreign(['reviewer_id','paper_id'])->references(['user_id','paper_id'])->on(['reviewer_paper'])->onDelete(['cascade']);
```

If it fails, you can also try this. :)

```
$table->foreign(['reviewer_id','paper_id'])->references(['user_id','paper_id'])->on(['reviewer_paper','reviewer_paper'])->onDelete(['cascade']);
```

And if this isn't supported in laravel, then you'll probably have to use the "via" field and/or loop manually.